# Firebase query wait for single value event listener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get data from `firebase` to update the contents in adapter. I need to wait for it to load the result asynchronously but `onDataChange` is never called. I'm using the following code:

```
class AttendanceAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private loginInfo_Collector mUserInfoCollector;

    private FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersInfoRef;
    private DatabaseReference mUser_dataAttRef;




    AttendanceAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        if(mRollDisplayList.isEmpty()) {
            loadDatabase();
            getCount();
        }



        return mRollDisplayList.size();
    }

 private void loadDatabase(){

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        mUsersInfoRef = mDatabase.getReference()
                .child(AttendanceActivity.mFacultyI)
                .child(AttendanceActivity.mYearI)
                .child("users");

        setViewContentsFromDb();


    }

    private void setViewContentsFromDb(){


            mUsersInfoRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if (mRollList.isEmpty()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot users : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            uIdList.add(users.getKey());
                            mUserInfoCollector = users.getValue(loginInfo_Collector.class);
                            mNameList.add(mUserInfoCollector.getName());
                            mRollList.add(mUserInfoCollector.getRoll_no());
                            mPhotoUriList.add(Uri.parse(mUserInfoCollector.getPhoto_url()));

                        }


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


    }
```

I've tried using while with condition that list is not empty else stay in empty loop but list is never updated.Is there any way to wait for query to finish before returning the result?

Database Structure:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1XXv.jpg)

Edit Solved: Moved the database code to before setting the adapter, and made the variables public and static to access them from adapter class.

Comment: You said "onDataChange is never called". In this case use `throw databaseError.toException();` in your `onCancelled`. Is there any exception?

Comment: i meant none of the code after adding the event listener is executed.It never checks datachange or cancelled.

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: Database structure image added.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, only the following lines of code are needed:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("BCT/2072/notice_node/users");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> mNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> mRollList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> mPhotoUriList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            loginInfo_Collector mUserInfoCollector = users.getValue(loginInfo_Collector.class);

            mNameList.add(mUserInfoCollector.getName());
            mRollList.add(mUserInfoCollector.getRoll_no());
            mPhotoUriList.add(Uri.parse(mUserInfoCollector.getPhoto_url()));

            Log.d("TAG", mUserInfoCollector.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the console will be the name of all users.

Note, a more elegant way would to create only a single `List<loginInfo_Collector>` and add objects of type `loginInfo_Collector` inside it and not create 3 different lists as you do.

Comment: No,still doesn't read .As soon as listener is added ,adapter sets with value 0 and nothing happens. And multiple list are for working on received data but thanx.

Comment: I solved it by moving code to activity setting the adapter and making variables static.

Comment: I don't understand how you solved this by making a variable static but glad to hear that you made it. Cheers!